# Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker minDate is not working as spected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Hello i'm new with this library and i wanted to set the minimum date = today, but when i select any date after today and try to select again today, it doesn't work, i'll show my small code and hope you to help me, thanks.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                format: 'D/M/YYYY',
                minDate : moment(),
                locale : moment.locale('es'),
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/65vaoqkw/7/)

Comment: it doesn't work yet, <code>moment()</code> is just a wrapper from the moment.js dependency of bootstrap-datetimepicker.js and it returns a <code>new Date()</code>

Comment: @Raviteja Would you be able to post the code from that jsfiddle as an answer?

Comment: I've noticed it only works when the default format is set, any other format won't let you re-select the minDate.

Comment: Well i found a solution, instead of setting `minDate : moment()`, i used `minDate : moment().subtract(1, 'day')`, i think that configuration works ( minDate, +infinite ]